# Make each button(color) from list turn background to correspondent color

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, tk-toolkit, for-in-loop

I want to make each button (under the colors list) change the (overall window) background color to the one from its name when clicked. I guess that's kinda what I aimed at with this part of the code in line 16:

```
command=window.configure(background=c)
```

But it doesn't work... 
I'd really appreciate a little help here.
Here's the full code:

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title("Colors")
window.geometry('650x300')
window.configure(background="#ffffff")

#Create a list of colors
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'orange', 'purple', 'white', 'black']

#loops through each color to make button
for c in colors:
    #create a new button using the text & background color
    b = tkinter.Button(text=c, bg=c, font=(None, 15), command=(window.configure(background=c)))
    b.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried window["bg"] = c    ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `functools.partial` to encapsulate the color value into a function (called a "closure").

```
from functools import partial

for c in colors:
    #create a new button using the text & background color
    b = tkinter.Button(text=c, bg=c, font=(None, 15), command=partial(window.configure, background=c))
    b.pack()
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You should make a function like this to change background colours and use functools.partial.

```
from functools import partial 
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title("Colors")
window.geometry('650x300')
window.configure(background="#ffffff")

#Create a list of colors
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'orange', 'purple', 'white', 'black']

def change_colour(button, colour):
    window.configure(background=colour)

#loops through each color to make button
for c in colors:
    #create a new button using the text & background color
    b = tkinter.Button(text=c, bg=c, font=(None, 15))
    b.configure(command=partial(change_colour, b, c))
    b.pack()

window.mainloop()
```